# Highlight var shipping block if text is

Tags: html, css, magento, html-table

Trying to see how to highlight this block if it is a certain text like UPS

Original code is

```
   <td style="border-right: 2px solid #808080;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;"
        valign="top">{{var shipping}}</td>
```

Modified code is

```
<td style="border-right: 2px solid #808080;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;" valign="top">
    {{if var shipping == "UPS"}} <span class="ups-shipping" style="color:#ffb500;">{{var shipping}}</span> {{else}} {{var shipping}} {{/if}}
</td>
```

Can't get it to work for some reason. Would appreciate any input. Thanks

EDIT: Found the php code below

```
<?php echo $shippingDescription ?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot a tag in your question

Comment: Since `{{var shipping}}` is not (processed by) HTML, nor is it CSS, there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: It's from a magento pdf invoice generator. That's the code I found in the invoice phtml

Comment: Updated to include php